# Configuring jboss-web.xml for isolated deployment to solve logs getting larger size

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss7.x, struts2

Continuing from my previous post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051282/eap-jboss-log-txt-file-getting-large-space, I'm using My Eclipse as ide for my project(Web project with Struts 2 & Hibernate 3). While deploying it on EAP jboss it genrated log.txt and populated to 2MB on each time link is hit. I tried to solve it through log4j.properties which i mentioned in the previous post's comment, doesn't solved it. When i gone through other sites they mentioned about isolated deployment by configuring jboss-web.xml. Since i'm using EAP 6.0 i couldn't find any help from other sites. When i tried that by http://planet.jboss.org/post/how_do_i_use_my_own_log4j_properties_or_xml_file_in_jboss  as

```
<jboss-web>
<class-loading>
    <loader-repository>
        com.emag:loader='com.emag.repository'
        <loader-repository-config>java2ParentDelegation=false</loader-repository-
config>
    </loader-repository>
</class-loading>
</jboss-web>  i got    javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[3,3].... How can i solve it? Please some one help me....
```

Comment: now i found that jboss-web.xml not needed for isolated deployment on EAP 6 since its using JBOSS AS 7. When i went through my EAP bin dir i saw my newly created file as empty and log.txt file is nearly 400MB size. i just tried to edit my new log file which created through log4j.properties, but not acccessible since its used by JAVA. So i could realized that my project is trying to use my file but jboss keep using log.txt. So please anyone help me to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try starting EAP Jboss by ./standalone.sh -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0 -Djboss.bind.address.management=0.0.0.0  -Dorg.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false

Check the link : https://community.jboss.org/message/788670#788670 for more details